# How to write different data type in one result column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, i have two columns in one table named tab1
1th column has type int, it is PK column with numerals
2nd one has nvarchar type.

```
ID     Name

1      Anna

2      Vladimir
```

What i want:

Result

```
ID_Name
1 Anna 

2 Vladimir
```

Comment: Hint : `CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use CONCAT function in your select:

```
Select Concat(ID, ' ', Name) AS ID_Name FROM tab1
```

Comment: OP wants a space between ID and Name.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),ID) + ' ' + Name AS ID_Name
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Although this will work here (varchar default size is 30 with CAST and CONVERT), it is strongly recommended always to use the length-param with (n)varchar...

Answer (score 2):

```
select concat(column1,' ',column2) from table
```

in your question, it will be

```
select concat(ID,' ',Name) from tab1
```

Answer (score 2):

your first column is of type **int** so you need to convert it intoor nvarchar to concatenate with name column wich is **nvarchar**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,ID) + ' ' + Name AS ID_Name
FROM my_table
```

also you can use **CONCAT** like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(ID,' ',Name) FROM my_table
```

Comment: Although this will work here (varchar default size is 30 with CAST and CONVERT), it is strongly recommended always to use the length-param with (n)varchar...

Comment: @Shnugo I know the default value is 30 characters but i don't think that INT value will exceed more than 30 characters.

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil maximum number of chars a conversion from int can be is 11, that's enough to cover the minimum value which use one char more than the maximum for the - sign. the problem, IMHO, is the inconsistency between `declare @s varcar` and `cast(@s as varchar)` - the first will result with the length  of one char while the second with a length of 30 chars. IMHO, That's a good enough reason why you should always specify the length, even when you know that 30 is enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can use (concat('column1','column2') as column name)

Comment: That would result in missing space between the two columns.

Comment: Nope.  This would create a string which reads "column1column2" .   remove the single quotes and add a space

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CONVERT() or CAST() string function while you want to use integer column concate with VARCHAR OR NVARCHAR column.

From SQL Server 2012 onward, you can use CONCAT() string function, which is take care of integer to string conversion.

Please check below select script.

```
SELECT
    *
INTO #tblA
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 ID,'Anna' Name UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ID,'Vladimir' Name
) A

SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11),t.ID) + ' ' + t.Name AS ID_Name
    --CONCAT(t.ID,' ',t.Name) AS ID_Name /*SQL Server 2012 Onwards*/
FROM #tblA t
```